# Autoclaving certain plastics?

Tags: equipment, cleaning

My professor is letting me use the autoclave in the future, but I am a novice. I asked him what materials were safe to autoclave for my notes, materials meaning glass or plastic-ware. He stated, "It depends on alot of factors, but some hard and opaque plastics are generally ok, also Teflon products."

I couldnt really ask him any more questions since it is still winter break and I guess he isnt responding to emails, so I decided to google the issue.

I found this source of an autoclave guide at: https://uwaterloo.ca/safety-office/sites/ca.safety-office/files/uploads/files/guideline-for-safe-use-of-autoclaves.pdf

> Good Choices:
>
> borosilicate glass (Pyrex) has very low thermo
> expansion property and therefore resistant to breaking due to heating
>
> polypropylene (PP) and polycarbonate (PC) are heat resistant plastics
>
> stainless steel is a good heat conductor and thus facilitates
> sterilization
>
> Poor Choices:
>
> polystyrene (PS), polylethylene (PE) and high density polyethylene (HDPE) do not resist heat well.
>
> if there is a risk of material melting ensure they are placed in a
> secondary container which is resistant to heat.

**Would this be an accurate  summary of what plastics / glassware to use in an autoclave?** I would ask about the validity of the website itself, but I assumed it was reliable because it was based off of a college.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list looks accurate. For example, the melting point of polypropylene ranges from ~130 C to ~160 C, so it's likely safe to autoclave.  Commercially available polyethylene melts ~100 -110 C, so is unsuitable for autoclaving.

Another common plastic, not listed above, polyethylene terephthalate (PETE), used for packaging and soft-drink bottles, softens below 100 C and is also unsuited for an autoclave.

Electrical and optical [items used in endoscopic procedures are often heat-sensitive and cannot be autoclaved, posing difficulties in removing contamination.](http://www.cdc.gov/hicpac/Disinfection_Sterilization/3_0disinfectEquipment.html#a2)

As suggested, if you're unsure but *must* autoclave an item, place it in an open or perforated container so as to reduce risk of damage to the sterilizer.